# Show reserved tables sql

Tags: sql

I made a table reservation system and I want to show the reserved tables so that people cannot choose the same table and same time but i'm not sure how to do this. some of the words are in dutch feel free to ask.

[image: This is the table]

This is the code that displays the info in the table.

```php
<?php  

 $query = "SELECT * FROM reservation ORDER BY reserve_id desc";  
 $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);  
 
?>
```

Comment: Not related to `Javascript` (nor to `php` in particular). The question is mainly of `SQL` database structure and query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Surely you don't just have a `reservation` *table*?
There should be a `table` *table* with table id and some other details (such as may be `capacity`, and then your `reservation` *table* can have `reservation_from` and `reservation_till`.

Once that is done, you will have to do a query that joins the tables and finds out which tables are available?

What is the `table_nr` column doing? That should ideally be the foreign key column, referring to the `table` table.

Comment: thank you now I know that I need to make a table named table in the database